# Netlify Form Submission

Tags: javascript, forms, netlify

I have this form here :

```
<form
          name="contact"
          method="POST"
          data-netlify="true"
          id="main-form"
          class="d--flex flex--column contact__form"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            class="bg--secondary"
          />
          <div id="nameError" class="error--msg">Please enter your name.</div>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            class="bg--secondary"
          />
          <div id="emailError" class="error--msg">
            Please enter a valid email adress.
          </div>
          <textarea
            name="message"
            id="message"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="Enter your message"
            class="bg--secondary"
          ></textarea>
          <div id="messageError" class="error--msg">
            Please tell me why do you want to contact me.
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn--secondary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

And I have some validation with javascript here :

```
function formError(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const nameValue = nameInput.value;
  const emailValue = emailInput.value;
  const messageValue = messageInput.value;

  if (nameValue.length <= 0) {
    nameInput.classList.add("error--border");
    nameError.classList.add("error");

    setTimeout(() => {
      nameInput.classList.remove("error--border");
      nameError.classList.remove("error");
    }, 5000);
  }
  if (!emailValidation(emailValue)) {
    emailInput.classList.add("error--border");
    emailError.classList.add("error");
    setTimeout(() => {
      emailInput.classList.remove("error--border");
      emailError.classList.remove("error");
    }, 5000);
  }

  if (messageValue.length <= 0) {
    messageInput.classList.add("error--border");
    messageError.classList.add("error");

    setTimeout(() => {
      messageInput.classList.remove("error--border");
      messageError.classList.remove("error");
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

The problem is since I use the preventDefault() this form isn't submitting anymore and if I take it out and I try to submit the form with errors for example I leave the name blank the JS still works and puts the error but my page reloads and not sure how to fix this problem, this is my first time I tried to do a form submission and if someone would give me any advice I will appreciate it alot!

Comment: Where is `formError()` being used?

Comment: I added a event listener on submit on the form